# how do I correct the AttributeError: module 'CV2' has no attribute 'videocapture'

Tags: opencv, attributeerror, video-capture

I wrote a QR code scanner program using Python.There was no problem in the code but when I ran it,the camera light came on and then turned off.The error message: AttributeError: module 'CV2' has no attribute 'videocapture'

I uninstalled the opencv library and reinstalled another one but the error continued to display.

Comment: Incorrect capitalization? Usually the OpenCV Python module is named `cv2`, not `CV2`, and the class in named `VideoCapture`, not `videocapture`. However, without seeing an [mcve], we can't tell for certain.